# log4net logs to file in IDE but not production

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, log4net

I'm building a C# WPF app for our company that uses APIs from our online platforms to pull data into a local database and then perform certain tasks with that data.

I opted to use log4net as it seemed to be the best solution for logging and our needs around it.

I set up the config file for log4net as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <log4net>
  <appender name="LogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\NUco Auctioneers\Integrator\Logs\Application_Logs.log" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %c%n%m%n%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="ErrorLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\NUco Auctioneers\Integrator\Logs\Error_Logs.log" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %c%n%m%n%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="FatalLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\NUco Auctioneers\Integrator\Logs\Fatal_Error_Logs.log" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="FATAL ERROR OCCURRED%n%d [%t] %c%n%m%n%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogAppender" />
  </root>
  <logger>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorLogAppender" />
  </logger>
  <logger>
    <level value="FATAL" />
    <appender-ref ref="FatalLogAppender" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

And I reference in App.xaml.cs code as follows -

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
log.Info("Log file created or appended.\nApplication is now running.");
```

This is my AsseblyInfo.cs -

```
// Log4Net
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

When running DEBUG in the IDE the logging works as intended, when running a production version logging does not work, no files are created and no logging occurs. Production version is installed with admin rights.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.2.6 on Windows 11. All NuGet packages are up to date.

Comment: 1. Are you sure the log4net.config is in the *current directory*? Note that the current directory might be different from the program directory. Better use an absolute path here. 2. Does the directory "C:\NUco Auctioneers\Integrator\Logs" exist or can be created and does the user running the application have write access?

Comment: Check The Event logs on Server to see if there are any errors.  If you are using Authentication the code may be running with the clients credentials and not Admin.